# Can I report all my taxable interest in Schedule CA NR Column E even if I wasn't a resident for the entire year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, compound-interest

Filing 2016 taxes. The place I having a savings account in reported $12 in 1099-INT.

I started living in California at the end of January. Will my taxes get rejected if I report all $12 in column E of line 8 in Schedule CA NR for 2016? Do I need to figure out what portion of the $12 I need to report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a CPA friend:

> Technically, you should prorate it, so $11, but that's minor. They're
>   not going to chase you down for a dollar.